# Como pasar una variable de una funcion a otra en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var n1 = 3;
var n2 = 4;

    function suma(){
     var suma = n1 + n2;
     console.log(suma);
    }

    function resta(){
    var resultado = suma - 3;
    console.log(resultado);
    }
```

Al momento de ocuparlo me dice que `resultado` esta indefinido. ¿Cómo puedo ocupar la variable `suma` en la funcion `resta`?

Muchas gracias

Comment: `respuesta` ??? donde esta respuesta

Comment: la variable `suma` solo esta definida en el bloque de la funcion suma. Quizas debas colocarla de forma global como `n1 y n2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me parece que la mejor forma de solucionar lo que pides es con algo asi:

```js
var n1 = 3;
var n2 = 4;

function suma() {
  return n1 + n2; // devolvemos el valor de la suma
}

function resta() {
  var resultado = suma() - 3; // ejecutamos la funcion suma y restamos el valor
  console.log(resultado);
}


resta()
```

Answer (score 1):

Declarando la variable suma como global

```js
    var n1 = 3;
    var n2 = 4;
    var suma = resultado = 0;
    
    function fsuma(){
       suma = n1 + n2;
       console.log(suma);
    }
    
    function fresta(){
      resultado = suma - 3;
      console.log(resultado);
    }
    
    fsuma();
    fresta()
```

de igual forma, también la variable resultado hacerla global por si la vas a utilizar en otra función u operación, igual te recomiendo cambiar el nombre de las funciones para que no sean igual que las variables, puede causar conflicto

Comment: Seguro que esa declaración de suma funciona?

Comment: no es mejor llamarle `sumar` a `fsuma` ó  `restar` a `fresta`

Comment: Solo es una prueba, el nombre puede quedar como se requiera, @element así es si funciona

Comment: Hablo de la asignación es rara

Comment: Es asignación o inicializacion a variables con el mismo valor, es preferible usar var variable1 = variable2 = 0; a var variable1 = 0; var variable2 = 0; es para optimizacion y ahorro de lineas código